# Time complexity for this relation - matrix chain multiplication

Tags: algorithm, recursion, big-o, time-complexity, matrix-multiplication

I think an (inefficient) recursive procedure for Matrix chain multiplication problem can be this (based on recurrence relation given in Cormen):

```
MATRIX-CHAIN(i,j)
    if i == j
        return 0
    if i < j
        q = INF

        for k = i to j-1
            q = min (q, MATRIX-CHAIN(i,k) + MATRIX-CHAIN(k+1, j) + c)  
            //c = cost of multiplying two sub-matrices.

        return q
```

Time complexity for this will be:

`T(n) = summation over k varying from i to j [T(k) + T(n-k)]`

Here, n = number of matrices to be multiplied.

What will be the value of T(n) and how?

Comment: should it be q = INF or q = max( )

Comment: Are you asking for http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number ? :)

Answer (score 1):

This is http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number

You can view the recurrence relation as doing parenthesis. The wiki page describes in depth how to arrive to the formula.

Comment: I don't know how to solve the recurrence relation I have mentioned (i.e. T(n) = summation over k varying from i to j [T(k) + T(n-k)]). So, how do I know that it translates to catalan number?

Comment: @jatin you are better off asking this question on solving recurrences in the mathematics forum .  The solution here is the Catalan Number .It is $\omega{2^n}$

Answer (score 0):

This might help:

you only have to work out each matrix-chain once (and store its value).

start = anywhere between i and j

end = anywhere between start and j

k = anywhere between start and end

if we think of a number with all 0's apart from three 1's (which represent start, k, end)

this special number has j-i+1 digits.

e.g. if i = 3 and j = 6 we need 4 digits giving us the following options:

```
1101 (i=3, k=4, j=6)

1011 (i=3, k=5, j=6)

0111 (i=4, k=5, j=6)

1110 (i=3, k=4, j=5)
```

number of choices for i,j,k = Combinations(3, j-i+1)

this is `n!/(k! * (n-k)!) = (j-i+1)! / (3! * (j-i+1-3)!)`